Dynamic Page Routing in Next.js 14 (app router) with WordPress as a Headless CMS
Could you please describe how page routing would be implemented in Next.js 14 using the App Router, considering the scenario where WordPress is employed as a headless CMS? This setup should accommodate both inner pages and posts authored within WordPress. The goal is to enable administrators to craft their own inner pages autonomously. Initially, the total number of pages is undetermined, and I prefer not to manually define each one, with the exception of the homepage. Below are examples of some of the pages:
Home
About
About/university
About/university/staff
Studies/study
Studies/admission
Studies/admission/graduates
Studies/admission/undergraduates
News (all news)
News/post slug

I have devised two potential solutions. The first involves creating a “pages” sub-folder with a catch-all route to handle all page requests, and a separate “news” sub-folder with another catch-all route dedicated to articles. The second solution entails establishing a single catch-all route "[..slug]/page.js", that retrieves the slug from the parameters, coupled with several conditional statements to manage the routing process.
What do you guys think?

This is actually not that hard to accomplish. Especially if you are fine to prefix your posts with /news/{slug}. I would create the following routes:

[..slugs] which will fetch pages by the provided slugs from the wp-rest api
/news/[slug] which can fetch the post by its slug from the wp-rest api

With these two routes you should be able to build all of your pages and render posts like you want to.
For a better page or post content render experience you could install Headless plugin which extends the rest api posts response with a json block structure.
You can have a look at my WordPress + Next.js Starterkit if you want to. It's not exatclty the same case but pretty close.
https://github.com/EdwardBock/wordpress-nextjs-starterkit/tree/main
